# Can I install USB 3.0 USB bracket if my motherboard does not support USB 3.0?

Tags: usb, pc, desktop, case

I have Gigabyte [GA-H61M-S](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S-rev-10/sp#sp) motherboard and it does not support USB 3.0.


My computer case has USB and Audio module but, its not working anymore. So, I am thinking to replace it with a good quality panel.


Now, I have found [this](https://www.amazon.in/Neon-Front-Panel-Connector-Adapter/dp/B073P4N21N/ref=pd_sbs_147_3/259-5822732-6957312?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B073P4N21N&pd_rd_r=13b75391-9d54-4dc9-b32f-bca5e1967ae5&pd_rd_w=zc4dW&pd_rd_wg=op5m8&pf_rd_p=fbf43daf-8fb3-47b5-9deb-ae9cce3969a9&pf_rd_r=M97ZDB2PY3ACQ8ABCHP4&psc=1&refRID=M97ZDB2PY3ACQ8ABCHP4) one product which meets my requirement. I have to connect it to USB header on motherboard. But, it says its for USB 3.0. 


So, my question is whether this panel will work or not with my motherboard. I know that if it works then it will give me speed of USB 2.0 only but, will it work at all or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an adapter for it because usb2 is 9 pin and your product mentioned is usb3 19 pin bracket so something similar like [this](https://m.snapdeal.com/product/eatech-025m-data-cables-usb/630967316260?gclid=CjwKCAiAo7HwBRBKEiwAvC_Q8QruRJVPUinQw68yzZHXJfRzjLJHKTmxC26q2gSKPNJpkM1cKTNbwhoCfNcQAvD_BwE&supc=SDL791484462&utm_source=earth_web&utm_medium=150_249&utm_content=630967316260&vendorCode=S9b203&isSellerPage=true&fv=true&utm_source=earth_pla&utm_campaign=Catchall_estimatedCM_New&utm_term=44394553586&utm_medium=44394553586&s_kwcid=AL!660!3!210325674210!!!g!301462959092!&ef_id=XgyPTgAAAHTTzs2g:20200101122342:s) can talk to both mother board and bracket.

[image: usb adapter]

Answer (score 0):

This will fit any motherboard with a free pci-e slot.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg2_2?ie=UTF8&adId=A05329332UIW0OA345RVE&url=%2FSIIG-Legacy-Express-External-Supports%2Fdp%2FB075SL611C%2Fref%3Dsr_1_28_sspa%3Fcrid%3D21UG840YWFFZA%26keywords%3Dpcie%2Busb%2B3.0%2Bcard%26qid%3D1579900980%26sprefix%3Dpcie%2Busb%252Caps%252C154%26sr%3D8-28-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1579900980&id=2883134542341984&widgetName=sp_mtf

[image]

NOTE I am not endorsing this model vs the 100 variations found on amazon.  Any will work to varing degrees.